# Spring boot ws: No adapter for endpoint

Tags: java, spring, soap, spring-boot, spring-ws

i'm trying to use spring boot ws in order to create a SOAP service, but i'm facing the exception "No adapter for endpoint...".

here is my xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://nisws.it.fastweb"
           targetNamespace="http://nisws.it.fastweb" elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="doEventRequest" type="tns:doEventRequest"/>

    <xs:element name="doEventResponse" type="tns:doEventResponse"/>
    <xs:complexType name="doEventRequest">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="header" type="tns:header"/>
            <xs:element name="trackingbody" type="tns:trackingbody"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="header">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="IdMessaggio" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="NomeBE" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="DataInserimentoBE" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Release" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="trackingbody">
        <xs:all>
            <xs:element name="Sorgente" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Parametri" type="tns:Parametri" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Componenti" type="tns:Componenti" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Parametri">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Parametro" type="tns:TagParametro" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TagParametro">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Descrizione" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Valore" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="Componenti">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Componente" type="tns:TagComponente" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="TagComponente">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Descrizione" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="Tipo" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="Parametri" type="tns:Parametri"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="doEventResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="header" type="tns:header"/>
            <xs:element name="trackingbody" type="tns:trackingbody"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Here is the class for the servlet

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.EnableWs;
import org.springframework.ws.config.annotation.WsConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema;
import org.springframework.xml.xsd.XsdSchema;

@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/nis/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "nisDoEvent")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema doEventSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("nisDoEvent");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/nis/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://nisws.it.fastweb");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(doEventSchema);
//      wsdl11Definition.setRequestSuffix("doEvent");
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean (name = "doEventSchema")
    public XsdSchema doEventSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("doEventSchema.xsd"));
    }

}
```

and here is my Endpoint

```
@Endpoint
public class CompletaMigrBNGEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://nisws.it.fastweb";

    private static final String EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE_URI = "http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service";

    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CompletaMigrBNGEndpoint(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        this.countryRepository = countryRepository;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "doEventRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public DoEventResponse doEvent(@RequestPayload DoEventRequest request){
        DoEventResponse response = new DoEventResponse();
        response.setHeader(request.getHeader());
        response.setTrackingbody(request.getTrackingbody());
        return response;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = EXAMPLE_NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCountryRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCountryResponse getCountry(@RequestPayload GetCountryRequest request) {
        GetCountryResponse response = new GetCountryResponse();
        response.setCountry(countryRepository.findCountry(request.getName()));

        return response;
    }
```

As you can see i also tried to follow the guide "https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/"

and the example provided works fine.

Regarding my own service I tried to call it via soapui and I get the exception:

```
16:43:38.674 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG o.s.w.s.server.SoapMessageDispatcher - Endpoint invocation resulted in exception - responding with Fault
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [public org.hp.doEventSchema.DoEventResponse org.hp.resources.connection.soap.services.CompletaMigrBNGEndpoint.doEvent(org.hp.doEventSchema.DoEventRequest)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.getEndpointAdapter(MessageDispatcher.java:302) [spring-ws-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.dispatch(MessageDispatcher.java:235) [spring-ws-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.ws.server.MessageDispatcher.receive(MessageDispatcher.java:176) [spring-ws-core-2.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/:2.2.1.RELEASE]
```

I believe that probably my error is in xsd or in endpoint mapping but i cannot fix it.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: Can you post the full config & pom file ? I have a service exactly like yours and its working fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved using JAXBElement to encapsulate my request/response object generated by jaxb plugin. This why i notice that in those classes there is no @XmlRootElement annotation.

Thanks anyway

Regards

Comment: If your answer solves the question you must accept it (even though you created the question). This will move the question to the "Answered" section.

Comment: You should post solution :(

Answer (score 5):

Just wrap the request and response with JAXBElement like below

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "doEventRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement< DoEventResponse > doEvent(@RequestPayload JAXBElement< DoEventRequest > request){}
```

we can get the object by calling like below

```
DoEventRequest d = request.getValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

Adding this answer since this is the top 1 result for the error message produced by Spring 6 / Spring Boot 3 / Spring WS 4 - `No adapter for endpoint` - too:

```
2023-05-11T18:11:02.816+02:00 DEBUG 75692 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.s.e.SimpleSoapExceptionResolver  : Resolving exception from endpoint [public MessageResponse com.example.ws.InboundEndpoint.message(com.example.inbound.Message)]: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint [public com.example.inbound.MessageResponse com.example.ws.InboundEndpoint.message(com.example.inbound.Message)]: Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
```

In my case this was caused by an outdated XJC generator that produced `javax.xml.bind` annotations.

From Spring WS 4, the framework only recognises `jakarta.xml.bind` annotations, e.g. [XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ws/blob/v4.0.3/spring-ws-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/adapter/method/jaxb/XmlRootElementPayloadMethodProcessor.java#LL41C32-L41C32)

Upgrading the XJC generator from `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:2.3.7` to a compatible version, e.g. `org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-xjc:4.0.1` solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Response Payload expects JAXBElement should pass both NAMESPACE_URI & Object in the QName. I have used below code snippet to resolve the issue.

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "ObjectName" )
    @ResponsePayload
    public JAXBElement<ResponseObject> methodName(@RequestPayload JAXBElement<Object> parameters) {

        //Method logic goes here

        return createResponseJaxbElement(response, ResponseObject.class);

    }

private JAXBElement createResponseJaxbElement(T object, Class clazz) {

    return new JAXBElement<>(new QName(NAMESPACE_URI, clazz.getSimpleName()), clazz, object);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. I updated the version of cxf plugin.

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

```
<cxf-xjc.version>4.0.0</cxf-xjc.version>
<apache.cxf.version>4.0.0</apache.cxf.version>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjc-utils</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf-xjc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${apache.cxf.version}</version>
<dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
                        <version>${cxf-xjc.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

and now the generated code uses jakarta.xml.bind.annotation